# `error: Could not deserialize` when importing a JAR file

Tags: java, scala, jar, databricks

I am using Databricks and I tried importing a JAR file of my Java/Scala project.

However, the import fails with this message:

```
Import failed with error: Could not deserialize: 
Unrecognized token 'Manifest': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')? 
at [Source: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.jar.JarArchiveInputStream@cb8cd3d; line: 1, column: 10]
```

Any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: Can you post the exact command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me. This is how i fix it.

> This error happens when you try to upload a library JAR via "Import" rather than "Create -> Library". So you should upload it by using "Create -> Library". Not the best UX, will be fixed soon.

[Source](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8953/error-could-not-deserialize-when-importing-a-jar-f.html)